# C# - Get a RTF-formatted string to a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, string, richtextbox, rtf

I have a RTF-formatted string that I want to load into a richTextBox, but the richTextBox only displays the text and not the formatting.

I'm using a richTextBoxExtended, which has a richTextBox which can be accessed as a normal RichTextBox using "richTextBoxExtended1.RichTextBox".

I've already tried to load the string into the Rtf parameter of the RichTextBox, as following :

```
string a = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1036{\\fonttbl{\\f0\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} \n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\i\\f0\\fs17 [FirstNames]\\i0\\fs17\\par\n}";           
richTextBoxExtended1.RichTextBox.Rtf = a;
```

It should display "[FirstNames]" in bold and in italic, but in only displays "[FirstNames]" without formatting.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Your code works well on new WinForms project I created with default RichTextBox, what is `richTextBoxExtended1` and its `.RichTextBox` member? What controls are you using?

Comment: I'm using this control :
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/richtextboxextended.aspx?fid=151897&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26#xx0xx

Comment: Hmm, sorry I missed text also should be Bold, not only Italic. I have text Italic, but not Bold using control you mentioned or default RichTextBox - you should check and validate your RTF I think.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved : it wouldn't get the format because the richTextBox was in a UserControl displayed in a Form. I moved all the code to a Form element, without the UserControl, and it worked.